# Github versioning: is it possible to have two separate sequences in the tags?

Tags: git, github, tags, devops, github-actions

I am working with Github actions and trying to implement a new strategy to deal with releases both for testing and for production. The idea is as follows:

There is a main branch for stable releases, and a develop branch with the latest code. You create a feature branch, make changes, and commit and push before merging into develop. This creates a version, say v1.5.4-develop. At some point, develop is merged into main to create a new version for production. This will follow its own numbering, independent of the develop sequence. So it might be v1.2.1 or something. Currently, I'm using the semantic-version action to create a new tag when merging into develop or main, and applying the suffix if it's the develop branch. This works fine, but when I merge into main it uses the latest tag in the repo.

I would like to find a way to get the most recent tag that **doesn't** have the develop suffix and increment that, so that the main releases follow their own sequence.

Example:

Latest main release: v1.2.3

Latest develop release: v1.4.6-develop

I would like the new main release to be 1.3.0, but currently it would be v1.4.6.

The code that creates the tag:

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: develop
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Bump version
        uses: PaulHatch/semantic-version@v4.0.2
        id: tag_version_develop
        with:
          tag_prefix: "v"
          major_pattern: "BREAKING CHANGE"
          minor_pattern: "feat:"
          format: "${major}.${minor}.${patch}"
          namespace: develop
          change_path: "."
          short_tags: false
          bump_each_commit: true
      - name: Tag Release (vX.Y.Z)
        run: |
          git tag ${{ steps.tag_version_develop.outputs.version_tag }}
          git push origin ${{ steps.tag_version_develop.outputs.version_tag }}
```

For the main release it's the same but without the namespace. I tried using a namespace of 'main' to see if that would look for the last tag with that suffix, but it didn't.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is really: "how do I control the behavior of PaulHatch/semantic-version@v4.0.2?"

Comment: @torek I suppose, but I can't see what I'm looking for in the docs. It retrieves the latest tag and bumps that - I would like to control the input for that, but I can't see an option for it.

Comment: I have no idea if it has such an option, but if it doesn't, perhaps some *other* semver software has it, or perhaps you should just write your own...

Answer (score 1):

use different tag_prefix for develop releases

Comment: Please include some code to demenstrate this